# Dynamically executing a query in array with bind_param PHP

Tags: php

i actually start using prepare statement and i find interesting but the path is actually not clear to me on how i can insert an array into a bind_param in prepare statement.

from the code below, i use the register_user function to grap all the $register_data which are username, password, email etc and i implode the $register_data in $data and the keys in $field but how do i bind  the array in the bind_param so my query can execute correctly and dynamically. Thanks

```
if (empty($_POST) == false && empty($errors) == true) {

    $register_data = array(
        'email' => $email,
        'username' => $username,
        'first_name' => $first_name,
        'last_name' => $last_name,
        'password' => $password
    );

    register_user($register_data);

    exit();

}


function register_user($register_data) {
    global $connection;

    array_walk($register_data, 'array_sanitize');
    $register_data['password'] = md5($register_data['password']);

    $fields = implode(', ', array_keys($register_data));
    $data = implode(', ', $register_data);

    $stmt = $connection -> prepare("INSERT into users ($fields) VALUES (?)");
    // the problem is around here
    $stmt -> bind_param('s', $data);
    $stmt -> execute();
}
```

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing, specially not using MD5() or SHA1(). PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks...Any idea on my question?

Comment: Generally you wouldn't do this.  You may be using a prepared statement, but you're still building that prepared statement from input.  Where does `$register_data` come from?  Can it be manipulated by a user?  We don't know, and this function doesn't do anything to prevent it, so this is a SQL injection vulnerability.  My question here is... Do you not know or control the schema of the `users` table?  If you don't, why not?  If you do, why can't you explicitly define your columns and bind your parameters?

Comment: @David, i have update the code, you can check how am parsing the $register_data now..

Comment: @David: The point remains... Define and bind your 5 fields in your prepared statement.  There's no need for an array at all here.  The SQL statement should be: `INSERT into users (email, username, first_name, last_name, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`  Then bind your 5 parameters.  In this strange effort to avoid having to explicitly write your 5 fields, all you've done is move those explicit fields slightly further away in the code.  You're still writing them, you're just adding a layer of indirection for no real reason.